# Need ID column to not be distinct when using a Sum aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT s.EmployeeID,e.LastName,projectID,sum(s.HoursWorked) AS Total_Hours
from TimeSheet s
full join Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
full Join Project p
ON p.ProjectID = e.EmployeeID 
group by p.ProjectID,s.EmployeeID,e.LastName
```

Which displays this

```
Employeid  Lastname        projectID    Sum(hoursWorked)
4          Peacock          NULL         33.00
5          Buchanan         NULL         44.00
1          Davolio          1            56.00
2          Fuller           2            41.00
3          Leverling        3            42.00
```

I want the project ID to show up for the 2 NULLS.

UPDATE: this is almost what i need.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(et.EmployeeID, p.projectID) AS employeeID
,       e.LastName
,       COALESCE(p.projectID, et.EmployeeID) AS projectID
,       sum(s.HoursWorked) AS Total_Hours
from    TimeSheet s  
inner join Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
inner join EmployeeTask et on e.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID
inner join Task t On t.TaskID=et.TaskID
inner join Project p on p.ProjectID=t.ProjectID 
group by p.ProjectID, et.EmployeeID, e.LastName
```

This produces

```
Employeid  Lastname        projectID    Sum(hoursWorked)
1          Davolio          1   112.00
2          Fuller           1   82.00
3          Leverling        2   84.00
4          Peacock          2   66.00
5          Buchanan         3   88.00
```

WHIch lead me to this link [Using multiple JOINS. SUM() producing wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303126/using-multiple-joins-sum-producing-wrong-value)

UPDATE ANSWER: which then i rewrote my sql to get the right answer.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(et.EmployeeID, p.projectID) AS employeeID
,       COALESCE(p.projectID, et.EmployeeID) AS projectID
,       e.LastName
,       (Select sum(HoursWorked)
    FROm TimeSheet
    WHere TimeSheet.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID
    )AS Total_Hours
from    TimeSheet s  
inner join Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
inner join EmployeeTask et on e.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID
inner join Task t On t.TaskID=et.TaskID
inner join Project p on p.ProjectID=t.ProjectID 
group by p.ProjectID, et.EmployeeID, s.EmployeeID,e.EmployeeID, e.LastName
```

Comment: `p.ProjectID = e.EmployeeID` is a bit suspicious.  For one thing, it means at most one employee can work on a project.

Comment: You were right so i when through other tables to connect the tables.

Answer (score 3):

u can use this query:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(s.EmployeeID, projectID) AS employeeID
,       e.LastName
,       COALESCE(projectID, s.EmployeeID) AS projectID
,       sum(s.HoursWorked) AS Total_Hours
from    TimeSheet s  
full join Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
full Join Project p ON p.ProjectID = e.EmployeeID
group by p.ProjectID, s.EmployeeID, e.LastName
```

because your projectid is equal to employee id, then if the join return null for ProjectID we can use employeeid instead

Comment: This give projectID 4 and 5, and there is not any projectID with that value. Employee id 1 and 2 are project id 1, Employee id 2 and 3 are project id 2,Employee id 3 is project id 3

Comment: This got me most of the way, there was still the problem of the single connect between ProjectID and employeeID, which i solved.

Answer (score 2):

the NULLs value saying that these 2 employees do not have any projects. By other words, there is no project having id 4,5

Answer (score 0):

From your database structure, I assumed that one employee is working for one project and all the timesheet is register for that project only. Personally I do not think this is a good db setup. It might not be used to store real data in real project.